# Android app for tracking time spent on pokemon go

Tags: android, time-management

I'm looking for an android app to track time spent specifically on Pokemon Go. I have installed [Screen Time](https://screentimelabs.com/), but i think it tracks the time the app was active and not the time the user was active playing the game.

Pokemon Go will track Pokemon nearby, it will also track how much a user walks, but i'm only interested in the time **actively** spent interacting with the game.